# Is linear discriminant analysis a supervised classifier or dimensionality reduction?

Tags: pca, discriminant-analysis

On page 147 of ISLR 2nd Edition, the author is talking about LDA and comparing it to a Bayes Classifier. This leads me to believe LDA is a machine learning algorithm for supervised classification. However, [in this post](https://vitalflux.com/pca-vs-lda-differences-plots-examples/) and various other posts online, LDA is compared to PCA as a technique for dimensionality reduction. So which is it, a supervised classifier or a dimensionality reduction technique?

You also have on page 148 (below) a confusion matrix of the results of the LDA classifier, which is further evidence that it is a supervised classifier and not a dimensionality reduction technique?

[image]

Comment: I'd say it was supervised (as it uses the class labels) dimensionality reduction (that can be turned into a classifier by applying thresholds)

Comment: I understand the supervised part. But I don't get the dimensionality reduction part. So you use LDA to "pca" your features, and then you run another LDA classifier to get class predictions?

Comment: LDA gives you a direction (and axis) in the feature space that optimises the separation of the classes (whereas PCA gives you a direction that maximises the variance of points in that direction).  You get the classifier by setting a threshold on the projection onto that axis.

Comment: I kind of understand the last point - basically the threshold defines how the classes are separated. However, by the same token, why cant we use PCA as a classifier as well if it does a similar thing (optimizes class separation via maximum variance)?

Comment: PCA doesn't aim to give axes that separate classes, just directions that maximise variance.  If you have two well-separated clusters, then the first principal component will be a reasonable discriminant that you could use for classification as it is likely that the direction of greatest variance will go roughly through the two cluster centers.  LDA will give a better discriminant though as it is designed for that purpose, whereas PCA isn't.

Answer (score 3):

LDA is a supervised classifier, no question about it. The referred post states it clearly in its second part:

> ### How does LDA work?
>
> Linear discriminant analysis (LDA) is another linear transformation
> technique that is used for dimensionality reduction. **Unlike PCA,
> however, LDA is a supervised learning method**, which means it takes
> class labels into account when finding directions of maximum variance.

It seems to me as if you're mixing some terms, so let's try to put some order in things:

- A supervised learning algorithm means that we have data $\{x_i\}$ with proper corresponding tags $\{y_i\}$ and we're trying to find a function $y_i=f(x_i)$ such that it minimizes a loss function $L(f(x_i),y_i)$ in the parametric case (leave the nonparametric methods aside for this discussion).
- An unsupervised learning algorithm means that we have data $\{x_i\}$ and no proper tags; Rather than finding a relation, we try to find a latent variable which explains an underlying property of the data, such as grouping to clusters, relations between covariates or simply division into classes.
- A dimensionality reduction method aims to take a $p$-dimensional dataset and reduce it to $k$ dimensions, obviously $k<p$, usually aiming to minimize loss of variance. These are not learning algorithms per se.

However, there is some relation between learning and dimensionality reduction: Methods such as [Factor Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) use dimensionality reduction in order to find the underlying linear structure of the covariates (read more about [SEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling)); The [wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_transform) regression lets the user reduce a huge proportion of the data dimensionality while still working under the label of supervised learning (a common example is the MNIST data).

---

Back to the original question (and the post), assume we have two $p$-dimensional data classes $A,B$ with probabilities mixture $\pi_A,\pi_B$, and assume they have a normal distribution (if not, you can always normalize the data) such that $(x_i|y_i=A,\mu_A,\Sigma_A)\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_A,\Sigma_A)$ and similarly $(x_i|y_i=B,\mu_B,\Sigma_B)\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_B,\Sigma_B)$. That's the basis of [Gaussian Discriminant Analysis](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103035702/http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes2.pdf), whose two most popular applications are Quadratic Discriminant Analysis and Linear Discriminant Analysis.

For LDA we further assume $\Sigma_A=\Sigma_B=\Lambda^{-1}$, so the discriminant line formula is

$$f(x)=(\mu_A-\mu_B)^T\Lambda x-\left( \log\frac{\pi_A}{\pi_B}-0.5\mu_A^T\Lambda\mu_A + 0.5\mu_B^T\Lambda\mu_B \right)$$

So in some essence - yes, we kinda reduce the $p$-dimensions into a linear formula - but this is not a dimensionality reduction method, in the same manner that a logistic regression on the same $p$-dimensional data (in which we have $\hat{\theta}_i=x_i^T\hat{\beta}$ and $P(\hat{y}_i=1)=sigmoid(\hat{\theta}_i)$ is not a dimensionality reduction method.